# NSPredicate searching NSSet

Tags: objective-c, regex, full-text-search, nspredicate

I've been looking around and have seen examples similar to what I am doing but can't get them to work. I have a "Product" core data entity that has a to-many relation ship with a "Manufacturer" entity. "Manufacturer" has a property "name" that I want to search against. "Product" also has a property of "isCustomItem" that I wish to search as well. So what I am I trying to reach looks like:

`Product` 1...m `Manufacturer.name`  AND  `Product.isCustomItem` == 0

This is what I've managed to get together so far:

```
NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(manufacturer,$m,$m.name CONTAINS[c] %@) AND (isCustomItem == 0)", searchString];
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
**'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(manufacturer,$m,$m.name CONTAINS[c] %@) AND (isCustomItem == 0)"'**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY manufacturer.name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
NSPredicate *customPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isCustomItem == 0"];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubPredicates:@[namePredicate, customPredicate]];
```

Then use compoundPredicate to filter your set.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am still getting this error when doing that: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY manufacturer.name CONTAINS[c] @%"'

Comment: It should be `%@`, not `@%`.

Comment: Bah, can't believe I didn't catch that either. That fixed it, thank you for the help!